# PostgreSQL group by but sort inside aggregation function (ST_Makeline)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a trajectory table in PostgreSQL and want to make polyline for each trajectory.

Each line of data contains `datetime` (datetime), `session_id` (string) and `geom` (Point geometry)

The goal is to construct each polyline with by all points following chronological order of `datetime`

I tried:

```sql
select session_id, st_makeline(geom) as geom
from trajectory
group by session_id
```

The code above gives me polylines of each trajectory, but for each polyline, the order was wrong.

How can I order nodes in the polyline so that they follow the order of datetime?

Comment: can you try this?

`select session_id, st_makeline(geom) as geom
from trajectory
group by session_id
order by datetime`

Comment: Sorry it has wrong syntax as im not selecting datetime at the first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `order by` clause to `st_makeline()`, as explained in [the postgis docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html):

```
select session_id, st_makeline(geom order by datetime) as geom
from trajectory
group by session_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `subquery` to `order by datetime` before calling `st_makeline()` function

```
SELECT gps.session_id, st_makeline(gps.geom) as geom
FROM 
    (SELECT session_id, geom
    FROM trajectory ORDER BY datetime) As gps
GROUP BY gps.session_id;
```